# What are the differences between High Volume Customer Portal license and Authenticated Website license?

Tags: customer-portal, licenses

There are cloudy differences mentioned [here](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_manage_users.htm#CPuserlicenses), but I feel there are more differences.
http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_manage_users.htm#CPuserlicenses

What are the differences between **High Volume Customer Portal** license and **Authenticated Website** license? *I am aware that these licenses are very similar and have very few differences between them.*

Is there any table explaining the differences between these two licenses?

> Edit: Please note that **High Volume Customer Portal** license is
>   different from
>   **Customer Portal Manager** license, hence my question is not a duplicate of this question:
>   [Customer Portal Manager vs Authenticated Website](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/customer-portal-manager-vs-authenticated-website).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main difference is the price and the objects you can access.  The following help page has more detail:

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm

Authenticated Web Site is the Platform Portal and has read and create access on ideas and questions and answers, and read-only access to documents, knowledge, price books, and products.

The High Volume Portal is the Service Cloud Portal and has access to accounts, assets, cases, contacts, custom objects, documents, ideas, and questions

The following Venn diagram by [Steven Herod](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/94/steven-herod) shows the relationships between the various license types:

[image: Salesforce Portal user licences]

Comment: http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_about_HVPUs.htm

Comment: Thing is, AWS is an HVP user.  Its just more restricted in terms of the objects it can access.

Comment: I did a venn diagram to try and demonstrate the differences about 2 weeks ago.  It's here.  http://limitexception.herod.net/2013/01/24/object-access-by-salesforce-portal-license/

Comment: Excellent diagram!

Comment: @StevenHerod That diagram is awesome!

Comment: Thank you @StevenHerod, BobBuzzard, and metadaddy! Do you have more differences other than Standard Object accessibility? **For example** I know that **Customer Portal Manager Custom** can access *Reports* but **HVCP** can not access *Reports*. So, are there such types of differences existing between **HVCP** and **Authenticated Website** licenses?

Comment: Awesome job putting this together!

Comment: @BarneyRubble No, HVCP and AW are in the same 'class' of license.  They share the same fundamental limitations which is they can't appear in Groups, don't have roles and have a different style of Sharing model.  The big difference between HVCP and AW is Case access and the positioning of it marketing wise by Salesforce.  I feel that HVCP is positioned to be used with a Customer Portal (Tabs / Standard UI / Page layouts).  AW is positioned to be used with a force.com site (Custom build in VF).  But you can use either license with either UI approach.